# Filtering a list in Objectify using Ref

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, objectify

How do i filter a list of an entity in Objectify which has Ref to another entity. The list should be filtered out based on a String field in the Ref entity.

public class AccountEntity extends BaseEntity {

```
@Index
private String accountName;
private String accountNo;
private String description;
private Integer displayOrderNo;
private Boolean contra = false;
private AccountingAccountType accountType;
@Index
private Ref<AccountGroupEntity> accountGroup;
@Ignore
private List<AccountEntryEntity> accountLedgerEntries;

public AccountEntity() {

}
```

[this is ref entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zfh9.png)

[filter code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaZ61.png)

Answer (score 1):

A ref is a key, so you can filter the key by passing in either a Key, Key<>, Ref<> or @Entity pojo.

You cannot however filter on a property of the entity that the key points to. To do this you'll need to denormalise that property into a separate indexed list in this entity, or create a lookup entity, similar to a join table.

Comment: Denormalization is a fundamental data modeling concept that you should understand - it is well covered on stack overflow. This answer is quite correct and gives you plenty of hooks for further research.